# NSCollectionView pinch zoom

Tags: cocoa, zooming, pinch, nscollectionview

I am trying to get pinch zoom in an NSCollectionView by implementing `-(void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event`, but I'm not sure on what to do inside this method. I'm getting the amount of the zoom with `[event magnification]`, and now I need to refresh the items inside the collection view.

I thought that I could save this in a variable `zoomValue`, and override the method `- (NSCollectionViewItem *)newItemForRepresentedObject:(id)object` in order to resize the view of each collection item (I think that this will not work, though. And anyway I don't know how to trigger the "refresh" of a collection view).

Any ideas about this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar, but from a slider instead of a pinch.
You just need to call:

```
[collectionView setMinItemSize:newSize];
[collectionView setMaxItemSize:newSize];
[collectionView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

To get the resize to happen live during the drag of the slider, I had to call a private method   -[NSCollectionView _updateGridWithCurrentItemsIfNecessary], otherwise the resize didn't happen until mouseup. Not sure if you'll have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Just a quick note, is the `_updateGridWithCurrentItemsIfNecessary` still there? I can't find it.

Comment: It's a private method so you won't see it in the documentation. Since it's private, it's important to wrap calls to private methods with respondsToSelector: checks. It was the only way I could find to make the view update immediately instead of waiting for the main event loop.